Dwarves as silicon life forms
So, I'm continuing to work on my sci-fi setting based on classic fantasy. Now I'm thinking about dwarves, and if earlier I took as a basis the classical idea of certain races and searched for a description of the planet for them, today I want to solve one question that I've been asking for some time.
Can dwarves be made of silicon living creatures? I know that silicon life forms are not scientifically confirmed, so I make a lot of assumptions in the creation of these dwarves. So, I would like to get creatures as close to classic dwarves as possible, but at the same time having silicon physiology. And in that case, I wonder if a silicon organism can even evolve into a humanoid undersized creature. Maybe not quite humanoid, or maybe not short, but still an intelligent creature capable of playing the role of a typical fantasy dwarf. In addition to height, intelligence and body structure, I am interested in a really long life expectancy of two or three hundred years, as well as a society with characteristics peculiar to dwarves: obsession with mining, beards (or maybe other external features), conservatism, touchiness. Their technological level is equal to the average throughout the galaxy (laser weapons, spaceships, and so on).
So, can such creatures evolve as silicon life forms?

I’m voting to close this question because (a) It's asking more than one question (VTC:Needs More Focus), (b) it violates the Book Rule (see [help/dont-ask]), (c) it's abusing the [tag:science-based] tag by failing to ask a [tag:science-based] question (fantasy can't be forced to be reality simply by using the tag...), and (d) it violates the [help/dont-ask]'s restriction against hypothetical questions even by our standards. (*Continued*)

... Questions on Stack exchange are expected (and we mean that) to be specific. You're asking us to create the entire creature (use tag [tag:creature-design]) for you. Worse, you want science-based answers on issues that aren't scence-based at all and you appear not to know that. There's no such thing as a silicon-based lifeform. Science is what you get when you have repeatable experiments. Speculation is what you have when you don't. You're confusing the two. But, to be clear, can fantasy creatures evolve as silicon life forms? Of course not, neither dwarves nor SBLs exist.

One last thing (and I'm doing you a favor). We've had a lot of people over the years that think crowbaring fantasy into science is worldbuilding. The most popular question asks for help making a science-based magic system. What does a [tag:science-based] dwarf look like? It looks like a human with one of the several forms of dwarfism who enjoys mine engineering and sports a long beard contrary to OSHA standards. Science is a harsh task master and really doesn't lend well to fantasy.

It's already hard to forecast that from a lump of self replicating carbon based matter a humanoid form can evolve.
Doing the same forecast for a silicon based life form, of which we know nothing more than "it is based on silicon" is almost an exercise in futility.
Then doing estimation on their life expectancy and social behavior goes even past that.
You are not writing your PhD thesis on exobiology, no need to insist on scientifically plausible things. We enjoy reading a story about a metal ring which can get molten only in a very specific place, when we know that it is totally unscientific.

Popular fiction depicts "silicon based lifeforms" as rock monsters. This is a misunderstanding of how that would work. Imagine if fiction identified "carbon based lifeforms" as diamond monsters for comparision.
This doesn't make your concept impossible. Take, for instance, your standard hemoglobin molecule.

This is an iron based molecule, but it doesn't have to stay that way. Take, instead, a magnesium based molecule of equivalent structure.

What is this odd molecule? It's chlorophyl. Yes, photosynthesis is performed with a molecule that looks an awful lot like the one we use to cart around oxygen.
Going another direction, I remember a Star Trek episode where it was commented that a monster couldn't hurt Spock because of his Vulcan green blood. Spock mentions that his blood is copper-based. I set this aside as Star Trek being weird, but it turns out that copper-based blood is actually a thing.

I present hemocyanin, the replacement for hemoglobin in cephalopods and crustaceans. The caveat being that the hemolymph is actually blue, not green.
So you want a silicon based life form? Sure. Just don't do it by replacing the carbon chains of life. Replace the entire structure of DNA with something more exotic that alternates carbon and silicon. Maybe it's a quad-helix, half silicon, half carbon. You could invent an unknown quantum effect (or insert other pseudoscience word) that gives the silicon bonds functionality that can't be achieved with carbon, similar to photosynthesis.

Thanks for your answer. When I asked the question, I really didn't understand that there was actually silicon life, so it seemed to me that the idea of stone dwarves was really good.

Not really, under the science-based tag. Silicon can bond to itself and to hydrogen in a very limited way, but compounds with Si-Si bonds are very reactive. Only Carbon has the ability to make large molecules using directional bonds. If your 'silicon' had this ability, then it would not be Silicon As We Know It Jim, and chemists will cringe when they read your book.
Unless your Dwarves are robots with semiconductor minds. That does not stop them being dwarves as we know them.
